# How to make group assignments for azure active directory roles?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, roles

I want to assign Azure Active Directory groups to an Azure Active Directory role. But if I open e.g. the role "Directory Readers" and click on "Add Assignment" I can only choose Azure Active Directory users but no groups.

How can I assign an Azure Active Directory group to an Azure Active Directory role?

Thank you in forward!

Best regards
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you could not assign an Azure Active Directory group to an Azure Active Directory role both in the portal and Powershell.

[image]

Here is a workaround. You could get members in the group first, then loop the members and assign members to the role.

```
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId {object id of group}

Foreach($member in $members){
    Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId {object id of directory reader role} -RefObjectId $member.ObjectId
}
```

If there is still a group in this group, then It will fail when assigning the role to the internal group.

Comment: That is not what I hoped for. But it's a way to do it. Thany you!